# Why does Hit Harivamsh place Radhaji above Sri Krsna?

Tags: radha

JSRK!

Why does Hit Harivamsh place Radhaji above Sri Krsna? I know they are worshipped together in all rasika sampraday, but Hitji is distinct for his view of Radharani.

JAI SRI MĀ!

Comment: Hit Sampradaya is Shakta Samradaya of Vaishnava Achara, hehe. Their Rasa is for Ladli Ju, why? Because, simply it's their own personal choice. For an example we can't question as why Shakta place Shakti above Shiva.  That is because their Guru and Acharya mandala do so. Hit Harivansh follows supremancy of Radha Rani just like Gaudiya follow Krishna. It's only the dofference of Achar otherwise Radha Krishna are one same Brahma expressed in two form.